# How can I execute a js script and send a var from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to solve an invisible reCaptcha with an API, but I don't know how can I execute the callback function and send the token with selenium.

Below is the snippet of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from anticaptchaofficial.recaptchav2proxyless import *


def solve_recaptcha(site):
    

    solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
    solver.set_verbose(1)
    solver.set_key("mykey")
    solver.set_website_url(site)
    solver.set_website_key("6LcmDCcUAAAAAL5QmnMvDFnfPTP4iCUYRk2MwC0-")
    
    
    g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
    if g_response != 0:
        return g_response
    else:
        return 0


site = 'https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-invisible.php'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='chromedriver.exe')    
driver.get(site)

g_recaptcha = solve_recaptcha(site)
driver.execute_async_script("var token = '{}'; onSubmit(token);", g_recaptcha)
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Submit ↦')]"))).click()
```

And this is the function:

```js
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
        }
```

I receive this message from the site:

> Note: Error code missing-input-response may mean the user just didn't complete the reCAPTCHA.

So, I'm not sure, but probably the the webdriver is not sending the var. And I don't know how should I proceed.

Comment: That function doesn't do anything with the token. You need to find the textarea and set it's innerText, and then submit the form.

Comment: I've tryied to send the token in the ```g-recaptcha-response``` , with this command: ```driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]""", g_recaptcha)```,and click on submit. But it doesn't work too.

Comment: Hmm, that looks right to me actually. Make sure the captcha is right and there's no callback.

Comment: There is callback actually.

Comment: You should update your question if the code has changed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem

I've finally managed to resolve this myself. In case anyone else is struggling with a similar issue, here was my solution:

- Open the console and execute the following cmd: ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients
- Find the path which has the callback function, in my case it's ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O
- Use the following code: driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O.callback('{new_token}')") (Remember to change the path accordingly)

This [Article](https://discourse.openbullet.dev/t/guide-recaptcha-v2-bypass-and-callbacks/3252) will help you to find the ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients of your recaptcha site

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response))   
time.sleep(3)  
driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O.callback('{g_response}')")
```